# how to measure execution time in specific part of View

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I want to calculate execution time in a specific part of View in MVC asp.net
for example

```
<p>start time is A</p>

<br />

@for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{

        if (@i % 100000 == 0)
        {
         <p>@i</p> <br />  
        }

}
 <p>End time is B</p>
<p>execution time is: C</p>
```

how to calculate A, B, C in above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@{
    DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    System.Diagnostics.StopWatch Watch = new System.Diagnostics.StopWatch();
    @Html.Raw("<p>start time is: " + StartTime.ToString() + "</p>");
    Watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {

        if (i % 100000 == 0)
        {
             @Html.Raw("<p>" + i.ToString() + "i</p> <br />");  
        }

    }
    Watch.Stop();
    DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Now;
    @Html.Raw("<p>End time is " + EndTime.ToString() + "</p>");
    @Html.Raw("<p>Execution time is: " + Watch.Elapsed.ToString() + "</p>");
}
```

Normally, I would recommend using a `StopWatch` to track the elapsed time but since you want the start and end times you might as well captured two dates and display the difference to calculate the time span.

Comment: Keep in mind that the resolution of `DateTime` is not that high.

Comment: Wait is not compiling or are you not seeing it on the screen? Also, let me fix the @ statements you have in your loop.

Comment: Html.Raw is not executed in this code, I don't know why, also TimeSpan gives error of an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Sorry that should have read `ElapsedToString` also Html.Raw needs @ before it.

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend you to do here is to create an instance of `Stopwatch` by `Stopwatch.StartNew`, execute your method or your code that you want to calculate execution time. Stop the `Stopwatch` where you think you method should be done with execution, and then get `ElapsedMilliseconds` like I will do in code below:

```
@{
  Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
  {
    if (i % 100000 == 0)
        {
             @Html.Raw("<p>" + i.ToString() + "</p> <br />");  
        }

    }
   stopwatch.Stop();
   @Html.Raw("<p>Elapsed time is: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "</p>");
}
```

And please, in case you might get an Error while you are trying to execute this code, be sure that you've included `System.Diagnostics;`

P.S If you don't like `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` you might check also for `stopwatch.Elapsed` to display elapsed time..

As I can see after Alexander's comment that you want start time, end time etc, what I suggest you to do here is to create a custom Stopwatch by inheriting `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`class and extending it with a couple of DateTime properties.

And I will now show you how you might do it:

```
public class MyCustomStopWatch : Stopwatch
{

        public DateTime? StartAt { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? EndAt { get; private set; }

        public void Reset()
        {
            StartAt = null;
            EndAt = null;

            base.Reset();
        }

        public void Restart()
        {
            StartAt = DateTime.Now;
            EndAt = null;

            base.Restart();
        }

        //This is what is important to you right now, to get data about that when you code started, and when your code finished with executing
        public void Start()
        {
            StartAt = DateTime.Now;

            base.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            EndAt = DateTime.Now;

            base.Stop();
        }


 }
```

If you are wondering **HOW COULD I USE THAT CODE**?

**DON'T WORRY**, HERE IS AN EXAMPLE BASED ON YOUR QUESTION:

```
@{
      MyCustomStopwatch stopwatch = MyCustomStopwatch();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      {
        if (i % 100000 == 0)
            {
                 @Html.Raw("<p>" + i.ToString() + "</p> <br />");  
            }

        }
       stopwatch.Stop();
       @Html.Raw(String.Format("<p>Stopwatch elapsed: {0}, StartAt: {1}, EndAt: {2} </p>", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), stopwatch.StartAt.Value.ToString(), stopwatch.EndAt.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Whatever I hope that you catch up the point and I hope that this helped you to solve your problem

Comment: He also wanted the Start Date and End Date

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins how could I know that? Where is that written, do I look a like a seer :) :) The only thing I can see in his question is a execution/elapsed time.. maybe I missed that somewhere but I really can't see where ..

Comment: The question asks to calculate and by inference print out A, B, and C. Your code is calculating and printing out B only.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins check for my edit.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro you answer is good, you've deserved up voting.

Comment: @DevX If it seems to be a good and helpful answer please accept so other user might recognize it as a good answer.